# Program "" not found in path

Tags: android, cygwin, cocos2d-x

So I'm trying to build the cocos2s-x HelloCpp sample for Android, and am running into this problem. Eclipse is giving me the error *Program "" not found in path*. Yes, the quotes are  empty. I'm not quite sure what program is is referring to. If I ignore the error and try to build by running build_native.sh in Cygwin, it gives the error:

Currently using: C:/cygwin64/bin/make

```
To solve the issue, follow these steps:

1. Ensure that the Cygwin 'make' package is installed.
   NOTE: You will need GNU Make 3.81 or later!

2. Define the GNUMAKE environment variable to point to it, as in:

     export GNUMAKE=/usr/bin/make

3. Call 'ndk-build' again.
```

This is very confusing to me, as I do have the GNU Make tool installed

Comment: There is a specific package of cygwin you need to install in order to invoke 'make'.  You'll see the option to install `make` in the devel group when installing cygwin.

Comment: As for the eclipse error I have no idea, I've always compiled coco2d-x for android via ant in command line.

Comment: I should have been more clear, I do have the GNU Make tool installed